# Checking network availability in iOS 7 for iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, network-connection

I see the answer already done on this page ([How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)), but since the answer is over 3 years old, is Method 1 of WasRobbed answer still the best way to check network connections in iOS 7?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reachability classes to check your internet connection download Reachability classes from here :-

```
https://github.com/preetlotey999/Reachability-Class-For-iOS.git
```

After see this Blog :- http://preetlotey999.blogspot.in/

This is a Blog for Developers to make it easy for Developing.

A very easiest way to show your internet connectivity.